# Let printed lines disapear in python

Tags: python

How can I tell my program to delete the previous text if <kbd>Enter</kbd> was pressed?

```
print('Information: \n ' )
input('Press Enter to continue.')
```

So if the user read the Info and presses <kbd>Enter</kbd> the text above still remains.

How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Following script can clear your screen

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call('cls',shell=True)
```